# Developing Sharepoint Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-7, sharepoint-2010, system-tray, windows

we want to have a tray windows application for our SharePoint users that they cant work with ms-access view or SharePoint workspace ... (this program should alert personnel with our custom alerts and they want customized small user interface for those end users.)

I use this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/566370/Developing-Sharepoint-Windows-Forms) and this [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/49016/5170) and write a simple code for Feasibility of this solution. but after build, this client side application seems to work only on that dev server.

we try it on the windows 7 and after 24 times that it need dlls like below list.

```
Microsoft.BusinessData.dll
Microsoft.HtmlTrans.Interface.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll
Microsoft.Internal.Mime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.AdministrationOperation.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Dsp.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll
Microsoft.Sharepoint.Sandbox.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.xml
Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll
Microsoft.Web.Design.Server.dll
```

still has another dlls.

```
Microsoft.sharepoint.intl.dll

Microsoft.SharePoint.CoreResource
```

that 'Microsoft.SharePoint.CoreResource is not exist in windows 2008 sharepoint 2010 dev server.

I know that this is not standard way to deploy it and I want to understand more and brief  about standard way to deploy and develop it on the clients.

I know that should my server has sharepoint 2010 64 bit but my clients are windows 7 32-bt. is this my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use server object model, only Client object model if you are running the application on a non-SharePoint server.
Server object model only works on the servers.

Please take a look at the [second link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49016/windows-forms-application-how-to-connect-to-fba-site)
You only have to reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Client DLL's.